# Rtf to txt on Unix

Tags: unix, batch, rtf

Can anyone recommend software (preferably freeware) for batch converting rtf files to txt files on Unix?

Comment: What format do you want the txt files to be? Stripped of all formatting, or somewhat richer, e.g. Markdown, like this site supports?

Answer (score 5):

There are many different ones, here are the ones I've tested successfully (all open source and free):

- unrtf
- wv
- unoconv

Comment: antiword doesn't work with rtf documents, as far as i can tell.

Comment: @dino: You are right, my mistake.

Comment: Tried these, but also wanted link information, without using full latex or PDF, so I use this too: `grep -ioP 'HYPERLINK "([^)]+)"' (xout) | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d '"'`

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention what flavour of UNIX but I think there's a textutil on many.

http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/TEXTUTIL/

```
 -convert fmt  Convert the specified files to the indicated format and
       write each one back to the file system.

       fmt is one of:  txt, html, rtf, rtfd, doc, docx, wordml,
               odt, or webarchive
```

Comment: That's only available on OS X. Check the bottom of the man page.

Answer (score 3):

There is "unrtf", but while the [Ubuntu package data](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/unrtf) claims that it can create text output, the [GNU unrtf homepage](http://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/) does not mention that format. But perhaps you can try that.

Comment: Ubuntu is right. The man page says:
--text selects plain ASCII text output.

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at an RTF file suggests that RTF markup is anything between `{braces}` and anything between a backslash and a space `\markup`. So maybe `strings` and a short sed/awk/perl script to delete markup would get you close to plain text.